# Swapping images in a table layout

Tags: android, imageview, tablelayout

I have a 2D array of ImageViews and am currently displaying each of them in a tableLayout. If I wanted to switch the ImageViews, I think that I need to swap the bitmaps that each [i][j] imageViews are assigned to. For example, if I wanted to swap positions of the images at [0][0] and [0][1], how would I do this?

I have a feeling that I would need to reassign each underlying bitmap to the appropriate imageview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try getting the Drawable, on the imageviews and save it to variables:

```
Drawable d1 = imageViews[0][0].getDrawable();
Drawable d2 = imageViews[0][1].getDrawable();
```

Then you swap the drawables by:

```
imageViews[0][0].setImageDrawable(d2);
imageViews[0][1].setImageDrawable(d1);
```

I think that will switch the images of the views, or do you actually need to move the positions of the imageviews?

Comment: thanks I definitely think this is the right track. Will I be able to click on these imageviews still and fire an event if I do this?

Comment: This will only change the image. So if you put some onclick things on imageView[0][0] this behaviour will remain on this object. (Is this what you want, or do you want the onlick behaviour to be related to the displayed image?

Comment: So I have a table of these imageviews and if I click on one, I want the adjacent view to swap positions with it.